# how to dynamically place components in form using angular

Tags: json, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I have to create a 2 column form where left and right side will have different `sections`/`groups` of elements. these sections are created as directives, now i have to place these directives in the form based on the column and postion values that I recieve from the `json`.

`{ group:"Group 1",column:1,position:2}` then `group1` directive should be placed on left side and in the second row of the left column. kindly suggest how to stitch these directives based on the position received

Comment: Your question is not so clear. please provide it with example code or fiddle.

Comment: i would sort your data first and ten place the directive accordingly

Comment: I cannot post code. To be more clear a form will have 6 sections 3 on each side(left and right) the sections person details, education, skill set, address, feedback and experience. for each section internally there will be input html elements. Now for each section i have created a directive. by default i know the order in which i have to place each section and in which column.Now requirement is to make directives reusables to create forms dynamically.now i am doing something like <div col-m-6><directive1/><directive2/><directive3/></div> for left part and on similar lines for right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can arrange your directives on the DOM as you want.
2. If you don't want to change elements on your DOM, You can create a directive with "C" or "A" as the required attribute (which means you can add it to any html element). Then, all you have to do is change the classes/ attribute on each position to get the desired result.

   ```
   .directive('InputA', function () {
       return {
               restrict: 'C',
                template... });

   .directive('InputB', function () {
       return {
               restrict: 'C',
                template... });
   ```

Then, your section can be like this:

```
<div col-m-6><div class="InputA"/><div class="InputB"/><div class="InputC"/></div>
```

than if you want to change the order all you have to do is change the classes to :

```
<div col-m-6><div class="InputC"/><div class="InputA"/><div class="InputB"/></div>
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/zmvr4tee/ - although i wouldn't recommend using jquery for the manipulation, i would create a parent directive that handles it but you get the idea.

**Update:**

added a function that recieveing a JSON, ordering it and place it according to column/position attributes.

```
 function build(){
 //you can play with column and position attributes to get different order

 //recieving the JSON  
 var inputs = angular.fromJson('[{ "label": "firstThird","column":1,"position":3},{ "label": "secondSecond","column":2,"position":2},{ "label": "firstSecond","column":1,"position":2},{ "label": "secondThird","column":2,"position":3},{ "label": "firstFirst","column":1,"position":1},{ "label": "secondFirst","column":2,"position":1}]' );

//sorting the input to match the right postition of each directive 
inputs.sort(function(a, b){
    return (a.column*2+a.position)-(b.column*2+b.position);
});

//positioning the directives according to their column and postiion attributes
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            $("#leftSection").children(':nth-child('+(i+1)+')').addClass(inputs[i].label);
        }
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            $("#rightSection").children(':nth-child('+(i+1)+')').addClass(inputs[i+3].label);
        }

        //compileing the form with angular to get the results
          angular.element($("#myForm")).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
            var scope = angular.element($("#myForm")).scope();
            $compile($("#myForm"))(scope);
        });
    }
```

see update Fiddle here:[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8aca4uy/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Initially form will be empty and it should get created from the directives. How do i may map the group name, column and position attributes of json to the form creation. You are switching the       directives based on button click

Comment: please describe how do you get the data amd what exactly in the JSON. the idea is to create a wrapping directive that will handle the mapping

Comment: [{ "label": "Personal Details","column":1,"position":1},{ "label": "Skills","column":2,"position":1}] this is the sample json